# Extract content of a single cell and separate and rename accordingly?

Tags: excel, vba, extract

So I have this large excel file, over 7000 rows, and what I need to do is pick the content from a cell in a column, for example A2, and extract its content onto A3

The thing is that the content are abbreviatures, like PRD for period, or CLS for class, all abbreviature are separated by underscores with no particular order, so for example A2 can just say PRD but B2 would say PRD_CLS_PPRD_ADVAN and then back to CLS_ADV on C2

What I need is to extract the content from each cell an put it on another cell, the abbreviatures must be replaced by it's original word so instead of PRD it should say Period, or Class instead of CLS, when there's an underscore it should be replaced for a slash. So overall when B2 says PRD_CLS_PPRD_ADVAN then B3 should say Period/Class/Pre-Production/Advance

I've given it a lot of tries to solve this, using LEFT, RIGHT, EXTRACT, but to no avail, would appreciate any suggestion on how to solve this

Comment: With formulae, I would use find() to identify the abbreviations and some helper cells to catch each one. Then a lookup to expand and & or concatenate the result. Pattern matching or vba would also work.

Comment: So for your example in A2, "=left(A2,find("_",A2,1)-1) will return "PRD".

Comment: Sorry you want vba.  You still need something that has the abbreviation and the actual word needed, but it can be a hard coded array.  Then `Split()` on the `_`.  Loop that array and replace the value in each item with the lookup from the lookup array and then use Join() to join it back together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, slightly different approach using find():

[image]

Formula for C2:

```
IFERROR(IF(FIND($E$2,$A2,1)>0,VLOOKUP($E$2,$E$2:$F$5,2,0),"")&"/","")&IFERROR(IF(FIND($E$3,$A2,1)>0,VLOOKUP($E$3,$E$2:$F$5,2,0),"")&"/","")&IFERROR(IF(FIND($E$4,$A2,1)>0,VLOOKUP($E$4,$E$2:$F$5,2,0),"")&"/","")&IFERROR(IF(FIND($E$5,$A2,1)>0,VLOOKUP($E$5,$E$2:$F$5,2,0),""),"")
```

Let you think about the trailing "/"...

Comment: Ok I got a further question regarding this, it has worked pretty flawlessly until I noticed something,
So I have some values like PRD for PRODUCTION and PPRD which is PREPRODUCTION, thing is that when it finds a PPRD it converts it into a "PREPRODUCTION/PRODUCTION" because it catches both the PPRD and the PRD inside of it.
How would you solve this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you look, I put PRD & PPD to sort that…

Comment: I do understand that and itt's a clever way to sort it out, the problem is that the table that  I am using does not allow for such changes. Im sorry for not being clear on that from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

'something like that should get you started

```
Public Sub convertCell()
Dim rowmax As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim StrArray() As String
Dim wrds As Integer


'replace sheet1 by the name of you sheets

rowmax = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To rowmax
    StrArray = Split(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1), "_")
    wrds = UBound(StrArray)
    
    For j = 0 To wrds
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) & "/" & StrArray(j)
    Next j
    
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: and you can keep a library of  abbreviatures in a hidden worksheets with the full definition. so they are easy to update and easy to access

Answer (score 0):

So basic method using formulae:

[image]

Formulae in C2:

```
VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,FIND("_",A2,1)-1),$E$2:$F$5,2,0)
```

Cells E2 to F5 hold the abbreviations, extend the range as needed.

So, update, been playing.

[image]

Just done the first two, use mid() for number 3 and right for number 4.